# If statement error "Expected Delceration"

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a simple "Guess How Many Fingers" app. Like the game you played in your childhood? Yeah that. I have a weird error on one of my if statements and it says "Expected deceleration" I just want if the value in the text box/field is equal to the random number to trigger a function.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
//Outlets
    //text box for guessing
    @IBOutlet weak var guessField: UITextField!

    //Correct or Incorrect Display
    @IBOutlet weak var yn: UILabel!

    //Label that shows how many guesses you have left
    @IBOutlet weak var guessesLabel: UILabel!


//Needed Variables
    var randomNumber = arc4random() % 6
    var guesses = 3
//Start Code

    if (guessField == randomNumber){
    //This is where the error appears^^        
    var yn = "Correct!"

    }else{

    guesses - 1
    var yn = "Try again!"
    var guessesLabel = "Remaining Guesses: " + guesses

    }
//Endgame function
    if (guesses > 1){
    var yn = "I was holding up \(randomNumber) fingers!"


    //Endgame function if 1 finger
    if (randomNumber == 1){

        var yn = "I was holding up 1 finger!"


        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
//Needed Variables
    var randomNumber = arc4random() % 6
    var guesses = 3
//Start Code

    if (guessField == randomNumber){
    //This is where the error appears^^        
    var yn = "Correct!"

    }else{

    guesses - 1
    var yn = "Try again!"
    var guessesLabel = "Remaining Guesses: " + guesses

    }
//Endgame function
    if (guesses > 1){
    var yn = "I was holding up \(randomNumber) fingers!"


    //Endgame function if 1 finger
    if (randomNumber == 1){

        var yn = "I was holding up 1 finger!"


        }

    }
```

To be:

```
func customFunction() -> //type {

//Needed Variables
    var randomNumber = arc4random() % 6
    var guesses = 3
//Start Code

    if (guessField == randomNumber){
    //This is where the error appears^^        
    var yn = "Correct!"

    }else{

    guesses - 1
    var yn = "Try again!"
    var guessesLabel = "Remaining Guesses: " + guesses

    }
//Endgame function
    if (guesses > 1){
    var yn = "I was holding up \(randomNumber) fingers!"


    //Endgame function if 1 finger
    if (randomNumber == 1){

        var yn = "I was holding up 1 finger!"


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the line `if (guessField == randomNumber)` and everything after that is not inside any function. You can't have executable code at the top level of a class declaration. That is why the compiler is telling you that you need a declaration (e.g. a function declaration) at this point.

Comment: I just started learning Swift this week. Could you explain how I fix this?

Comment: @chaserobbins, see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1.guessField is a textfield which will contain a string.(and even for string it is guessfield.text)

2.you are comparing a integer to string.

So fix is

```
NSString *strVar=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",var];
if[(guessField.text isEqualToString strVar]){
   // Your code----
}
```